# Basic Python Sound Programming

Tags: python, audio

How can I make a program that plays a tone that I define while I hold down a key? I can play different notes with winsound.Beep(), but I don't think this really helps.

Comment: "I don't think this really helps" doesn't give much away in terms of what your criteria are.

Comment: I just mean to say that I have tried using the winsound library for this to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to use the standard library and youre using, you can use msvcrt to get the current keypress and map that to a frequency.

```
import msvcrt
import time
import winsound

notes = {'a': 440, 's': 935, 'd': 1039}

while True:
    key = msvcrt.getch()
    try:
        note = notes[key]
    except KeyError:
        note = 0

    winsound.Beep(note, 10)
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

Comment: This just repeats the beeping (or as it plays on my computer, more of a clicking) rapidly when the button is held down. I mean to have a smooth tone while the note is held down. Is this possible with winsound or will I need a different library?

Comment: I did that partially out of memory, my current computer doesnt seem to support the Beep function, I thought at one point I got it to be constant but I might be wrong.

Comment: @Paul The second argument to `winsound.Beep()` is the duration of the beep in milliseconds.  You could embiggen that number to get a longer note, but if you're using `getch()` for input, there's no way for the program to be aware of how _long_ you're holding down a key.

Comment: In that case, is there something other than winsound.Beep() that can be used to play a sound while something is occurring like a key press?

Comment: Maybe pygame? or just pregenerate the audio.

Answer (score 0):

The [winsound](http://docs.python.org/library/winsound.html) module allows you to play more than just beeps, have a look at [`winsound.PlaySound`](http://docs.python.org/library/winsound.html#winsound.PlaySound):

```
winsound.PlaySound('mySound.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)
```

When the user holds down a key, you will generally get multiple key press events in a short time.

Comment: I've looked into PlaySound, but I'm just interested in getting a smooth tone at a frequency described by the program.